# Is there a limit to how often you can convert a Traditional IRA to a Roth IRA within a given time period?

Tags: united-states, ira, roth-conversion

Is there a limit to the number of times you can convert a Traditional IRA to a Roth IRA within a given time period? For example, if I convert my existing Traditional IRA to a Roth IRA now, and then want to take advantage of a Backdoor Roth IRA conversion later this year, will that be allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert additional amounts from Traditional IRA to Roth IRA as often as you want.

What there is a limit on, is "reconversion" -- if you convert to Roth IRA, then recharacterize it back to Traditional IRA (undoing the conversion), then you are restricted from "re-converting" that money to Roth IRA again in the 30 days after the recharacterization or during the same tax year as the original conversion.